# Tratando erro em campo de busca com texto e inteiro (Django)

Tags: django, django-filter

O código a seguir faz uma busca de valores no template. Mas ele localiza por texto, e quando eu digito, por exemplo, 2015 para localizar pelo ano, ele retorna um erro porque o campo deve ser um inteiro e não um número, como tratar este erro para que ele localize pelo ano?

```
p = Proposal.objects.all().select_related()
q = self.request.GET.get('search_box')
if not q in [None, '']:
    p = p.filter(
        Q(id__icontains=q) |
        Q(work__name_work__icontains=q) |
        Q(work__customer__first_name__icontains=q) |
        Q(category__category__startswith=q) |
        Q(employee__user__first_name__startswith=q) |
        Q(seller__employee__user__first_name__startswith=q) |
        Q(created__year=q)
    )
```

Vejam o erro:

```
ValueError at /proposal/
The __year lookup type requires an integer argument
```

No caso, quando eu digito um ano dá certo, mas quando eu digito outro texto dá erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é você passar um parâmetro informando o que o usuário deseja buscar e com isso realizar uma filtragem específica, do jeito que está o filtro está retornando qualquer resultado que conter a palavra buscada, o que não é uma boa prática.

**O certo seria:** (passando informação através do template)

```
especifico_por = request.GET.get('especifico', False)
if especifico_por == 'ano':
    p = p.filter(created__year=q)
elif especifico_por == 'cliente':
    p = p.filter(work__customer__first_name__icontains=q)
# e assim por diante...
```

**Do jeito que você está fazendo não é recomendado**, você teria que verificar se esse `q` é um ano ou não, uma forma seria usando `exception`:

```
try:
     p = p.filter(created__year=q)
except TypeError:
     pass

p = p.filter(
    Q(id__icontains=q) |  # id__icontains não faz sentido algum
    Q(work__name_work__icontains=q) |
    Q(work__customer__first_name__icontains=q) |
    Q(category__category__startswith=q) |
    Q(employee__user__first_name__startswith=q) |
    Q(seller__employee__user__first_name__startswith=q) |
)
```